# Getting an attribute from a different Entity

Tags: java, android, entity

> How do I get an attribute of a different Entity using entity relationships?

[image: See photo for reference]

I have an entity called **jobOrderEntity**. It has a relationship with Checkout. I wanted to access **payment_method attribute** from **checkout** using relationship but it returns null.

[image: This is the checkouts]
[image: This is the attribute I want to get from Checkouts]

```
if (this.jobOrderEntity.relationships.checkout.data.attributes.payment_mode.equals("cash-on-delivery")) {
   //my code here
}
```

Comment: Hi, you definitely need to give more context for your issue.
A good start will be to use:
 '"cash-on-delivery".equals(this.jobOrderEntity.relationships.checkout.data.attributes.payment_mode)` 
instead to avoid NullPointerException.

Comment: @BaptisteM I edited my question and added some pictures. I want to get the payment_method attribute from checkouts.